# Unhandled StackOverflow Exception in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

In our
**production**
server, we have a service(32-bit) which have a code of **unzip file.**

We have around 15 instances such services with different name but all the services are deployed using one build. Which means -

> Service1 -> Service.exe (a saperate folder with all the DLLs and
> configs)
>
> Service2 -> Service.exe (a saperate folder with all the DLLs and
> configs) and so on.. till Service15

It works well with small zip file. The problem we are facing is that when we get **a large zip file like greater than 6 GB**, our service throws ***StackOverflow Exception.*** and crashes.

```
Fault bucket 2244167076755370166, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Service.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: e39527e5
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.7.3946.0
P6: 624721ef
P7: 3fb6
P8: 0
P9: System.StackOverflowException
P10:
```

The Code -

```
private string ExtractZip(string ZipFileName)
{
    try
    {

        if (ZipFileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".zip"))
        {
            string workingDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnzipConsoleWorkingDirectory"];
            string exeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnzipConsoleName"];

            HTech.Tools.Debugging.Sentinel.Trace("Chilkat Process Starting");
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + ZipFileName + "\"";

            p.Start(); //Crashes here

            p.WaitForExit();
            HTech.Tools.Debugging.Sentinel.Trace("Chilkat Process End");
        }

        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(ZipFileName);
        string extractedFolderName = finfo.DirectoryName + "\\" + finfo.Name.ToLower().Replace(finfo.Extension.ToLower(), "");
        
        if(Directory.Exists(extractedFolderName))
        {
            return extractedFolderName;
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HTech.Tools.Debugging.Sentinel.Trace("Error In ExtractZip" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Unzip Code (DotNetZip)-

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fPath))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(finfo.DirectoryName + "\\" + finfo.Name.ToLower().Replace(finfo.Extension.ToLower(), "")) == true)
                Directory.Delete(finfo.DirectoryName + "\\" + finfo.Name.ToLower().Replace(finfo.Extension.ToLower(), ""), true);

            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fPath))
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
                {
                    e.Extract(finfo.DirectoryName);
                }
            }
        }
```

While the same code on **SIT** server works properly for same file. But on SIT, We have *only 2 instace* of this service due to lesser load of process.

I have tried to saperate the code for **unzip** in another saperate process and calling it from the service. But its still crashing.

*Is there any chance that the number of instances of this service is the reason behind this issue? Becuase the same service working on SIT environment where instances are less. Or any other issue? How to avoid this Stackoverflow ?*

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible for us to help

Comment: If the code still crashes when running in another process, you should be able replicate the issue when running in a debugger. A stack overflow exception should be fairly easy to diagnose if you get a complete call stack.

Comment: @Charlieface Code Added

Comment: @JonasH How can i run debugger at prod server? The issue is not replicable on local environment. Its only happening on prod server where we have 15 such services as I mentioned above.

Comment: just stop other 10-12 processes and run that large file (mimic lower environment). it might be memory issue.
StackOverflowException is thrown for execution stack overflow errors, typically in case of a very deep or unbounded recursion. So make sure your code doesn't have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

Comment: @PowerMouse - Is there any other way we can follow? Like without stopping those processes. And renaming this one particular process with some other name ServiceAlternate.exe ? will that help?

Comment: This isn't showing the code that actually causes the crash. Please show the relevant code of the `UnzipConsoleName`application

Comment: it possible that HD does not have enough space (including C drive where temp folder) so it crashes on unzipping large files? since we did not see code which causing crash i can only assume.

Comment: You may be able to use the [remote debugger tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2022). But if you have different behavior on different computers you probably want to find out why. You should have a test environment that is as close as possible to prod to help find issues related to the OS, memory, etc.

Comment: @PowerMouse, Can it we the case related to number of services? As I have 14 and each have approx 5 individual threads. So they might be making the stack full. is it possible?

If thats the case how can I start a process independently which is in fresh thread instead of parent thread? Also would like to know when the process ends notifier.

Comment: @ArpitGupta, i dont think it related to number of services, as i see each service have a unique name so it would execute its own instance. and as you mention that it runs on lower environment with less instances means there is no issues. i would check resources, maybe use different architecture/libraries, etc..  might check different unzip libs such as WinRAR (have better memory management on large files), etc...
but mainly, check disk space on C drive and on drive, where you extracting..  and memory

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Chilkat for the actual process. You are not showing the actual code for that aspect. Most likely, you are not checking the success code returned from the Chilkat process. If the success code shows a failure, be sure to log the content in the LastErrorText.

Something along the lines of:

```
Chilkat.Zip zip = new Chilkat.Zip();

bool success = zip.OpenZip("my_files.zip");
if (success != true) {
    Debug.WriteLine(zip.LastErrorText);
    return;
}
```

Comment: No, Its not related to chilkat. I have changed that chilkat code into DotNetZip and still faced same issue.
And If I talk about chilkat case, It actually gets crashed in OpenZip code itself which you given in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching back to ***Chilkat*** and using the options below to get better visibility into the crash:

**DebugLogFilePath**:
If set to a file path, causes each Chilkat method or property call to automatically append it's LastErrorText to the specified log file. The information is appended such that if a hang or crash occurs, it is possible to see the context in which the problem occurred, as well as a history of all Chilkat calls up to the point of the problem. The ***VerboseLogging*** property can be set to provide more detailed information.